# How to debug issue with 220v AC motor that blows internal fuse

Tags: motor, induction-motor

I've got a 220v dust collector (shopfox w1666) that consistently blows the internal 18amp fuse shortly after it turns on. Video here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyB6S.jpg

I think this started happening after I had plugged it in while it was switched on. There was some burn marks and pitting on the plug after it arced when I did that.

I've replaced the fuse and the motor start capacitor but that hasn't helped.

What is the likely source of this issue? what steps can I take to debug it further?

I have a pretty rudimentary ability to diagnose and resolve electrical problems, and hope that this question is appropriate for electrical engineering stack exchange!

Answer (score 1):

Run capacitor would be a suspect (50uF/350V it looks like, get a replacement from Grizzly or their recommendation).

Or the motor may have an internal shorted winding.

Comment: I've already replaced the capacitor, first with a generic one off ebay (200MFD 250VAC CD60A 200uF, TMC UL) and then with the official one from grizzly PX1666008A-1

Comment: are there steps i can take to determine if there's a shortened winding? is this something i can fix myself, or take somewhere to fix?

Comment: RUN capacitor not start capacitor. If the motor has a shorted winding it is not economical to repair so you would replace it.

Comment: ah ok, i don’t believe this w1666 has a run capacitor - i see the older generation did but i am not seeing one i could replace. appreciate your attention on this, sadly sounds like it won’t be fixable